# If (X,$\tau$) Hausdorff, then $Der(E) \in \tau^* \ \forall E \subseteq X$

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove that if (X,$\tau$) Hausdorff, then $Der(E)\in \tau^* \ \forall E \subseteq X$. Der(E) is the the derived set. (= set of all accumulation point). In the proof $\overset{\text{---}}{E}$ stands for the closure of E. Iso(E) is the set of isolated points.

This is what I got so far. I try to prove that $X \setminus Der(E) \in \tau$.
We know that: $$ \overset{\text{---}}{E} = Der(E) \sqcup Iso(E)$$ Also, $Der(E)= \overset{\text{---}}{E} \setminus Iso(E)$. \
Then we can write that:
$$X \setminus Der(E) = (X\setminus \overset{\text{---}}{E} ) \cup Iso(E) $$
We know for sure that $ (X\setminus \overset{\text{---}}{E} ) $ \is open. We just need to show that Iso(E) is open. In general this is not the case, but we have Hausdorff.

If $p_0 \in Iso(E)$, then $\exists U \ \in \mathcal{U}_p \ U \cap E = \{p_0\}$.

I take a point q $\in V$ con q $\neq p_0$,then it exists $V \in \mathcal{U}_q$. For sure $p_0 \notin V$ because the topology is Hausdorff.

But then the intersection between U V and E is the empty set.

Quindi $q \notin \overset{\text{---}}{E}$. 
Then $q \in X \setminus  \overset{\text{---}}{E}$.

Then $U\setminus \{p_0\} \subseteq X \setminus  \overset{\text{---}}{E}$.

So we have $U \subseteq X \setminus  \overset{\text{---}}{E} \cup Iso(E) $.

Then $ U \subseteq X \setminus Der(E).$ But this means that $U \cap Der(E) = \emptyset$.

But $p_0 \in U$ for sure so  $p_0 \notin$ Der(E). Quindi $p_0 \in X \setminus Der(E)$.

Now I do not know how to conclude.
Can someone help?

Comment: What does quindi mean?  Does it mean therefore?

Comment: The derived set, written A', is the set of all limit points.  How are you defining accumulation point?

Comment: Yes, it means therefore, sorry about that. An accumulation point p is defined by: $$ E \cap ( U \setminus \{p\} ) \neq \emptyset $$ Where U is a neighborhood of p.

Comment: That is a limit point.  An accumulation of A is a point x with for all open U nhood x, A intersection U is infinite.  The terms have been known to vary from text to text.

Comment: What does the unusual notation $\tau^*$ mean?  The set of closed sets?

Comment: What does $\tau^*$ mean?

Answer (score 0):

If A is a subset of a T1 space S, then
A' (the derived set of is A) is closed.

To show S - A' is open, assume x in S - A'.
Thus some open U with x in U and empty U $\cap$ {A - {x}).

If y in U, y /= x, then y in S\A'.  Proof:
y in open U - {x};  (U - {x}) $\cap$ (A - {y}) is empty;  y not in A'
As x in S - A', altogether U subset S - A' and S - A' is open.

Notice that only T1 is needed to show A' is closed.
For other spaces there is the theorem
(for all x, {x}' is closed) iff (for all A, A' is closed).